# smiley face of counter with d_flip flop

Tags: vhdl, counter, bit, state-machine, vivado

I'm trying to write a code with VHDL for smiley face counter, with flip flop
but i got some errors that about "width mismatch" and i dont know exactly what's a problem.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Smiley_Faces is
    Port ( Clk, Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end Smiley_Faces;

architecture Behavioral of Smiley_Faces is
signal NS, PS:std_logic_vector(5 downto 0):= (others => '0');
begin
--- Memory Component
D_ff:process(reset,clk)
begin
if(reset='1') then
ps <= "0000";
elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
ps<=nS;
end if;
end process;
-- Combination Logic
NS <= "010000" when ps="000000" else
     "000110" when ps="010000" else
     "010110" when ps="000110" else
     "001111" when ps="010110" else
     "011111" when ps="001111" else
     "101111" when ps="011111" else
     "111111" when ps="101111" else
     "000000" when ps="111111" else
     "000000";
Q <= PS;
     
end Behavioral;
```

[The pic attached about state machine of smiley face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0pJY.png)

Comment: You should consider using a "case" statement instead of the "when" constructs. The "whens" introduce a  priority of checks which is not needed. In hardware this means you will get a deep combinatorial path with perhaps bad timing. If you would use "case" the hardware will be a multiplexer, which will switch faster.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things

1. You set PS with a bit width of 6 but your reset statement is only assigning it with 4 bits

   ```
   if(reset='1') then
   ps <= "0000";`
   ```
2. You are assigning Q with the value of PS, but they are not the same bit widths. Either you need to update Q to be 6 bits or edit the code to be:

   ```
   Q <= PS(3 downto 0);
   ```